# Why am I getting a meesed up cout statement from my function?

Tags: c++, function, structure

Hi I am working on a program that should display the latter of two dates, it needs to accept two Date structures and return the latter of them. Latter being 04/31/2014 is latter then 04/30/2014. Here is my code and I do not understand why I am getting a long weird number... Thanks for helping.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

int main()
{
    void laterDate(Date, Date);
    Date one;
    Date two;
Date later;

cout << "Enter a Date starting with the day, then month, then year:\n";

cin >> one.day;
cin >> one.month;
cin >> one.year;

cout << "\n\nEnter another date in the same fashion as above:\n";

cin >> two.day;
cin >> two.month;
    cin >> two.year;

cout << "\n\nThank you, I will now tell you which date is later then the other!" <<             endl;
laterDate(one, two);

system("pause");
return 0;
}


void laterDate(Date o,Date t)
{
Date later;


if (o.year >= t.year)
    if (o.month >= t.month)
        if (o.day > t.day)
        {
            later.day= o.day;
            later.month = o.month;
            later.year = o.year;
        }
        else
        {
            later.day = t.day;
            later.month = t.month;
            later.year = t.year;
        }

        cout << later.day << "/" << later.month << "/" << later.year << endl;
}
```

***OUTPUT***
Enter a Date starting with the day, then month, then year:
04
30
2014

Enter another date in the same fashion as above:
04
31
2014

Thank you, I will now tell you which date is later then the other!
-858993460/-858993460/-858993460
Press any key to continue . . .

***END OUTPUT***

Comment: your function only sets `later` if your first two if statements are `true`. Add enclosing braces and mentally step through your code, this isn't very difficult to debug.

Comment: Is it solid code aside from my bug? And the enclosing braces should i enclose each if within the other?

Comment: Check your conditions. This only works in the case of when the first date entered is later than the second date entered.

Comment: @MjsGoku: it's not solid aside from this bug. A problem in the input stream may cause `one` or `two` to be incompletely initialized.

Comment: Could you elaborate so I know what to fix and to prevent it in future projects? Should I use cin.get()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (o.year > t.year || 
   (o.year >= t.year && o.month > t.month) || 
    (o.year >= t.year && o.month >= t.month &&
           o.day > t.day))
        {
            later.day= o.day;
            later.month = o.month;
            later.year = o.year;
        }
        else
        {
            later.day = t.day;
            later.month = t.month;
            later.year = t.year;
        }
```

in this way , else will always be called , in your implementation it is only called when the two first condition where true, resulting in the display of random bits

Comment: i was confused by the if statement, you are definitly right

Comment: Thank you Boo, i found your code to be most in line with my level of knowledge and the easiest to comprehend and i have not been able to break it yet, Thank you again.

Comment: You could also have written `later = o` instead of copying each individual piece since the element-wise copy operator is automatically generated.

Answer (score 1):

You should break out the logic of comparing the dates from the code which displays the results. The standard idiom for comparing objects that can be totally ordered (such as dates) is to overload `operator<`.

```
// the intent of this function is to return true if lhs precedes rhs,
// and return false otherwise (rhs precedes lhs, or they are equal)
bool operator<(Date const& lhs, Date const& rhs)
{
    // first test the year.
    // if the years differ, there is no need to test the month or the day
    if (lhs.year < rhs.year) return true;
    if (lhs.year > rhs.year) return false;

    // years are equal, test the month
    if (lhs.month < rhs.month) return true;
    if (lhs.month > rhs.month) return false;

    // months are equal, test the day
    return lhs.day < rhs.day;
}
```

Then your function can be easily written like this:

```
void laterDate(Date const& lhs, Date const& rhs)
{
    Date const& later = (lhs < rhs) ? rhs : lhs;

    cout << later.day << "/" << later.month << "/" << later.year << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok I do not really understand overloading operators, the two projects I am working on right now other then this one requires me to overload operators, so this code might help me with those as well!

Comment: No, you can take the arguments in by value, if you want to. That will make unnecessary copies, which is not too big of a deal in this case (since the objects are not too big), but no harm in being consistent.

Comment: So you recommend byRef in this instance?

Comment: I recommend taking the arguments by const reference (I'm not sure why you're saying "byRef")

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr.Lindley, I feel this answer is above my comprehension, I understand the logic of using a Bool, and I see how this would work, I just do not know if I know how to structure my program with overloaded operators which is why I chose the if statement, I do hope you help me on my next project though, and you seem like you can provide a vast wealth of knowledge I would love to one day have!!! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd structure things a little differently.  First, I'd make outputting a `Date` a friend function of the `Date` class and next, I'd overload the `>` operator for comparing `Date` class instances.

```
struct Date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Date &d) {
        return out << d.day << "/" << d.month << "/" << d.year;
    }
    bool operator>(const Date &t) const;
};
```

The implementation of the `>` operator would look like this:

```
bool Date::operator>(const Date &t) const
{
    if (year > t.year) return true;
    if (year < t.year) return false;
    if (month > t.month) return true;
    if (month < t.month) return false;
    return day > t.day;
}
```

And then your `main` routine would be this:

```
int main()
{
    Date one;
    Date two;

    std::cout << "Enter a Date starting with the day, then month, then year:\n";
    std::cin >> one.day >> one.month >> one.year;
    std::cout << "\n\nEnter another date in the same fashion as above:\n";
    std::cin >> two.day >> two.month >> two.year;
    std::cout << "\n\nThank you: " << (one > two ? one : two) 
              << " is the later date\n";
}
```

Note, too, that one can chain the input operator parts as shown here.  In fact, I'd be inclined to declare an input operator `operator>>` and promote the `Date` struct to a full-fledged class.

Comment: Thank you Edward, i decided not to go with the bool method you and Mr.Lindley provided, but thank you for helping me the code you guys wrote i'm hoping will help me on my next to projects!!!